# How to remove Login Item (SMLoginItemSetEnabled set to NO) by the application that NOT installed them

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Official Apple's documentation Daemons and Services Programming Guide says "There are two ways to add a login item: using the Service Management framework, and using a shared file list

Login items installed using the Service Management framework are not visible in System Preferences and can only be removed by the application that installed them"

The question is about "can only be removed by the application that installed them"

I know some app, that can remove any Login Item.

How to do that?